# How do I prove that a vector space endomorphism is a commutative ring if and only if the vector space has dimension 1?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $V$ be a vector space over $k$. Show that $\mathrm{Hom}(V,V)$ is a commutative ring (with respect to addition and composition of functions) if and only if $V$ has dimension $1$.

We know that $\mathrm{Hom}(V,V)$ is a ring (with respect to addition and composition of functions) and would like to prove that it is commutative.

If $V$ has dimension $1$, then every $v\in V$ is a multiple of some $v_0\in V$, and every $T\in\mathrm{Hom}(V,V)$ is a scalar multiplication. By commutativity of scalar multiplication, $\mathrm{Hom}(V,V)$ is a commutative ring.

Now, given that $T_2\circ T_1=T_1\circ T_2$ for every $T_1,T_2\in\mathrm{Hom}(V,V)$, how do we show that $V$ has dimension $1$?

Comment: I would do the contrapositive: show that if the dimension is at least $2$, then you can find two endomorphisms that do not commute.

Comment: (Technically, the endomorphism ring of the zero vector space is also commutative, as it is the zero ring)

Comment: Here's a hint.
Let $\operatorname{dim} V\geq2$ and
let $e_1,e_2,\ldots$ be a basis of vector space $V$. Take homomorphisms $f$ and $g$, which are given on the basis by formulas:
$$
f(e_1)=e_1,\ f(e_i)=0;\quad g(e_1)=e_2,\ g(e_i)=0;\ i\geq2.
$$